# pandas value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

this is my code:
my dataframe DF is based on this:
index             int64
FiscalYear        int64
GL               object
GLID              int64
GL_Debit        float64
GL_Credit       float64
month            object
Solde de fin    float64

```
DF.sort_values(by=['GL', 'month'], inplace=True)
                    DF['Variation des périodes'] = DF.groupby([ 'GL'])['Solde de fin'].diff().fillna(DF['Solde de fin'])
                    DF = DF.rename(columns={'GL_Debit':'Débit année à date','GL_Credit':'Crédit année à date'})
            
for i in range(len(DF)):
                row = DF.iloc[i]
                teste = row['month'][5:7]
                if row['month'][5:7]=='04':
                    if row['GL'][0] in ['4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']:
                        DF.iloc[i]['Variation des périodes'] = row['Solde de fin']
                    else:
                        DF.iloc[i]['Variation des périodes'] = row['Variation des périodes']
```

I've this error:
SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
DF.iloc[i]['Variation des périodes'] = row['Solde de fin']

and

DF.iloc[i]['Variation des périodes'] does not show me row['Solde de fin']

Comment: Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) and at [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution:
replace bloc by loc and do not have warning and values are god!

```
DF.loc[i, 'Variation des périodes'] =row['Solde de fin']
```